# How to read value of a signal boolean in Angular17

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a singal in service:

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}
  url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login';
  token: string = '';
  isAuthenticated = signal<Boolean>(false);
  changeIsAAuthenticated() {
    this.isAuthenticated.set(false);
    console.log(this.isAuthenticated);
  }
  getIsAAuthenticated() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }
```

and in route guard i want to get its value:

```
 let authService = inject(AuthService);
 console.log(authService.isAuthenticated);
```

and i get:

```
function getter()
```

How to read a value of a singal?
I tried:
getValue, value, get or writing a getter but it didnt work.

```
console.log(authService.isAuthenticated);
  console.log(authService.getIsAAuthenticated());
```

return `function getter()`

I should have see the value just by console.log it, but it doesnt work.

EDIT:
i have a function:

```
 getIsAAuthenticated() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }
```

but the console log of it:

```
  console.log(authService.getIsAAuthenticated());
```

returns:

```
function getter
```

so it does not work

Comment: You call it,  `return this.isAuthenticated()`, see https://angular.dev/guide/signals

Comment: Please note `Boolean` is the constructor not the type `boolean` so it'd be more correct to do `isAuthenticated = signal<boolean>(false);` but the type is inferred in simple cases like this so `isAuthenticated = signal(false);` is preferred

Comment: thanks sir for your answer! sadly, it doesnt work

Comment: you're doing return this.isAuthenticated; not this.isAuthenticated();